# python spur ssh check if file exists

Tags: python, ssh

I am using spur in python to ssh into a linux server and it's doing everything I want it to, except, I am unsure of the best way to use spur to ssh into the linux server and check if a file exists on that server. I am currently doing it this way, but it is quite slow, is there a quicker way?

```
import spur
shell = spur.SshShell(hostname="192.168.0.22", username="username", password="password", missing_host_key=spur.ssh.MissingHostKey.accept)
inFile = "/home/myFolder/Desktop/fileNmae.avi"
try:
    result = shell.run(["ls", inFile])
    print "Pass"
except:
    print "Fail"
```

Comment: You should consider using SFTP for this rather than plain SSH. SFTP has functions for this kind of thing.

Comment: why and how would I use SFTP?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [spurplus](https://github.com/Parquery/spurplus) that we developed since we found paramiko and [spur](https://github.com/mwilliamson/spur.py) to be both a bit too low-level. Here is an example how to check if a file exists:

```
import spurplus

with spurplus.connect_with_retries(
        hostname='some-machine.example.com', username='devop') as shell:
    file_exists = shell.exists("/path/to/some/file")

    pth = pathlib.Path("/path/to/another/file")
    another_file_exists = shell.exists(pth)
```